# Firebase: How to unsubscribe all tokens from a specific topic?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app i am subscribing users on different topics when needed but i want to **unsubscribe all users from a specific topic after a particular time** from server (API) not from device. After reading different answers here and on other platforms i came to know that it's not possible to delete a topic but topic will be deleted automatically when there is no token registered to it.

So i am asking if there is any way to unsubscribe all tokens from a topic or delete a topic using API not firebase console? Thanx

Comment: Where do you want to execute this command to unsubscribe. Unless I'm mistaken, each client must issue their own unsubscription from a topic.

Comment: i want to unsub tokens from server rather than on devices. In simple words i do not want users to be subscribed after a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control subscriptions from the server, you will need IID tokens for each client that you want to modify.  There is [documentation that describes the HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances) for this.

> **Create a relation mapping for an app instance**
>
> Given a registration token and a supported relationship, you can
>   create a mapping. For example, you can subscribe an app instance to a
>   Google Cloud Messaging topic by calling the Instance ID service at
>   this endpoint, providing the app instance's token as shown:
>
> `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME`
>
> **Manage relationship maps for multiple app instances**
>
> Using the Instance ID service's batch methods, you can perform batch
>   management of app instances. For example, you can perform bulk
>   addition or removal of app instances to an FCM or GCM topic. To manage
>   app instances, call the Instance ID service at this endpoint,
>   providing the app instance tokens in the JSON body:
>
> `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd`
>
> `https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove`

Comment: Thanx Doug. But i know this and read the documentation. I wanted to know if there is any way to unsubscribe all instance ids from a topic without knowing about them like tell firebase that i have this "abs_topic" please unsub all tokens against this topic.

Comment: Not possible, according to the capabilities described by the docs.

Comment: i think firebase is saving tokens against topics then why not give developer access to delete it or delete topic directly.Anyway Thanx Doug for trying to help me.

Comment: If you're trying to do something outside the documented features, please file a feature request.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I can't believe Firebase does not allow for deleting Topics or finding out who is subscribed to a topic and then remove them all from that topic.  This makes no sense.  As the administrator, we should have the right to delete topics as necessary as well as remove all users from a topic - regardless of reason.  But if a topic is retired or changed I don't want users having lingering subscriptions to topics that no longer exist.  Why does google do this?  Besides "because its google", what reason/justification is there for NOT having a delete topic OR remove all devices/users from a topic?